# get this errors on below sentence Invalid expression term '<' & ; expected & Invalid expression term ':'

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is my code, I got it

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>GridView With ModalPopUpExtender</title>
```

> Error 1   Invalid expression term
>   '<'   C:\Users\Nehal\Desktop\modalpopupcontrol\Default.aspx   1   1   C:...\modalpopupcontrol\
>   Error 2   ;
>   expected  C:\Users\Nehal\Desktop\modalpopupcontrol\Default.aspx   1   1   C:...\modalpopupcontrol\
>   Error 3   Invalid expression term
>   ':'   C:\Users\Nehal\Desktop\modalpopupcontrol\Default.aspx   1   1   C:...\modalpopupcontrol\
>   Error 4   ;
>   expected  C:\Users\Nehal\Desktop\modalpopupcontrol\Default.aspx   1   1   C:...\modalpopupcontrol\

Comment: Jab in the dark, but does `modalpopupcontrol\Default.aspx` have its Action property set to `Compile` instead of `Content` in your Visual Studio project?

Comment: Not sure but doesn't the `register` directive need `src` as well?

Comment: Can we see some more code please?